# Best way to call Api from Web Api Project

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a .NET Core Project in which I need to create an API that will call another API(outside of this project) .
And I've got a problem , because I don't want to make external API call from a controller , because as I understand - controllers should be only called from the API and reroute data  .
Task of my API is to authenticate and authorize a user and if he has rights for it - call external API .
I thought about creating a Service that will call external API , but I'm not sure that it would be good idea to keep this logic in same Web-API project.
What will be the best option to do this - create a library or something else to make external API call?
I attached a scheme to show what I mean .
[image]

Comment: It doesn't have to be a library, you could just make a wrapper or layer for that API.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can be pragmatic. Why is calling the External API directly from your API a problem? We are missing several of the details that could make this an interesting question. Also, might be better for the Software Engineering forum.

You have a few options:

- Directly call the external API from the client. If there is additional server side processes that are needed maybe this isn't an option.
- Directly call the external API from your API project.

A wrapper library just make another layer of indirection that I'm not sure you'd benefit from at this point. If you are worried about keeping the code clean, look at using something like Mediatr so that your controller classes aren't littered with code.

Comment: Task of my API is to authenticate and authorize a user and if he has rights for it - call external API .   
I thought about creating a Service that will call external API , but I'm not sure that it would be good idea to keep this logic in same Web-API project.

Comment: Why not? If you move it out of that project you just created  more work for  yourself.  Do you think it will cause you some kind of issue down the road? Look into CQS and Mediatr if you really want to write cleaner code in the future. At this time it probably pays to be pragmatic and keep it in the same project. Also you might want to look at Polly for retry policies if this is an important part of your app. https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly